# cassandra, aws and No node was available to execute the query

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, cassandra

I try to connect app and aws cassandra, and I have an exception "No node was available to execute the query". I'm trying to work with java, Spring Data and examples from the aws. I absolutely know that I have a connection to this db but I don't know how it works and I want to point out that I've already created a keyspace. What works wrongly? How can I check the nodes? It's a little strange. I don't even know how I can solve it and my knowledge in this area is little. I even ask how and what I need to check.
It's my config file.

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig {

    private final String username = "...";
    private final String password = ".";
    File driverConfig = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/application.conf");

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public CqlSession session() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return CqlSession.builder().
                withConfigLoader(DriverConfigLoader.fromFile(driverConfig)).
                withAuthCredentials(username, password).
                withSslContext(SSLContext.getDefault()).
                withKeyspace("my_keyspace").
                build();
    }
}
```

and another one

```
datastax-java-driver {
basic {
  load-balancing-policy {
    local-datacenter = us-east-1
  }
  contact-points = ["cassandra.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:9142"]
  request {
  page-size = 3500
  timeout = 40 seconds
  consistency = LOCAL_QUORUM
 }
} 
advanced {
 control-connection {
  timeout = 40 seconds
}
 connection {
 connect-timeout = 40 seconds
 init-query-timeout = 40 seconds
}
 auth-provider {
  class = PlainTextAuthProvider
 }

 ssl-engine-factory {
  class = DefaultSslEngineFactory
 }

 metadata {
 token-map.enabled = false
 schema.enabled = true 
 }
 }
}
```

and exception

```
CassandraConnectionFailureException: Query; CQL [CREATE TABLE ............ WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);]; No node was available to execute the query; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
```

Answer (score 1):

local-datacenter = us-east-1. It was my fault.